# letsencrypt webroot gives 404 for nginx located in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, certbot

I have a simple docker container run in the following way:

```
docker service create --name nginx_proxy \
  --mount type=bind,source=/opt/nginx/conf.d,target=/etc/nginx/conf.d \
  --mount type=bind,source=/opt/nginx/webroot,target=/var/webroot \
  --constraint 'node.role==manager' \
  --publish 80:80 --publish 443:443 \
  --network nginx-net \
  nginx
```

The created service runs without issues. I added a sample configuration that proxy passes to another service in the same network (example.com.conf):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    alias /var/webroot;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://example_site:8080;
  }
}
```

When I go to (www.)example.com, I can see my website.

Since I mounted host:/opt/nginx/webroot to container:/var/webroot, I created a file in /opt/nginx/webroot called "test.html" (contents of the file do not matter).

When I open my browser and type in:

```
http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test.html
```

I can view the file that I added to /opt/nginx/webroot. However, certbot throws 404 when I run the following command:

```
certbot certonly --dry-run --webroot -w /opt/nginx/webroot -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

What am I missing here? To my understanding, certbot creates a file in webroot directory and tries to download the file publicly; however, it doesn't see my file for some reason.

Comment: can you post the logs of certbot and nginx?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem might be due to a misunderstanding of the -w in the certbot command.
-w or --webroot-path  specifies the top level directory containing the files served by your webserver.

Certbot will create subfolders to this for the acme-challenge, in your case certbot will create `/opt/nginx/webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge/` but your nginx configuration points to the webroot itself.

https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#webroot

Consider changing

```
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    alias /var/webroot;
  }
```

to something like this

```
  location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
    alias /var/webroot/.well-known/acme-challenge;
  }
```